# streaming views in ruby on rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, http-streaming

I am new to rails, and ruby for that matter.  I have built up a rails app based on ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1

I have run into an issue, probably with my understanding of the streaming implementation in rails.  It seems to me that before rails will render the template content, it must complete the process of evaluating it.

let's say for example that I have a cgi script like the following

```
#!/bin/sh


cat <<END
Content-Type: text/html

END

for i in {1..10}
do
 echo $i
 sleep 1
done
```

this will display the numbers sequentially from 1 to 10 in the browser as they are rendered by the script, not all at once.  This is the behaviour I would like to emulate in a rails view.

lets say I have the following in a view.

```
<h1> hi </h1>
<%
sleep 5
%>
<h2> bye </h2>
```

it will wait until the sleep 5 completes before displaying anything.

using curl -i to watch the response from the web server i get the response header immediately as expected with Transfer-Encoding: chunked as expected.  however it does not render the body contents until the sleep completes.

what do I need to do to have it render the body content in the same manner as that simple cgi script I pasted above?  Specifically, first the `<h1> hi </h1>`  then 5 seconds later the `<h2> bye </h2>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [ActionController::Streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html). To wit:

> Streaming can be added to a given template easily, all you need to do is to pass the `:stream` option.
>
> > ```
> > class PostsController
> >   def index
> >     @posts = Post.scope
> >     render :stream => true
> >   end
> > end
> > ```

You'll want to read the rest of the docs for the details, of course.

Comment: correct and that is what I have  in the controller it has `format.html { render :stream => true }` and with curl I can see it streams the response header, and the layout, but not the contents of the template.